# Transform bitmap characters into triangles

Tags: javascript, character, html5-canvas, webgl

I am attempting to use an html canvas element to draw each character available in a font file to a canvas. To make this question as simple as possible, pretend only one character is drawn to a canvas. From there, I want to use Javascript to analyze the canvas and create triangle regions of the canvas that make up the entire character. The reason I need it in triangles is so that the data can later be sent to WebGL so text can be rendered and data will not be lost be scaling the text size up or down.

I am looking for some sort of algorithm to accomplish this or at least some knowledge to get me going in the right direction. If you believe I should use a different approach please tell me why, but I figured this would be the best to provide a way to modify text in many ways as well as make it possible to create 3d block text.

Comment: In 3D graphics, text is rendered using a type rendering library to a texture and presented to the user on a rectangle surface rather than to a 3D object. Also, the task of reducing rendered type to triangles is non-trivial (because fonts aren't simple vertex/edge structures, but mini-programs in themselves, and use smooth curves such as Beziers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an article on how to draw resolution independent curves with shaders

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/cloop/loopblinn05.pdf

My understanding is instead of breaking the shapes into triangles you break them into quads with enough info sorted in the vertices to draw a portion of the curve inside each quad. In other words, as the shader draws each quad there's a formula that for each pixel can compute if that pixel is inside the curve or outside the curve.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to start with the keyword [Polygon Triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation).

Using this methods, you can split n-Polygons into triangles like this:
[image: Image from abovementioned Wikipedia-Article]

These methods may only apply to figures with real (and not rounded) edges.

Answer (score 0):

So, you are trying to convert a raster image into vector data?
When zoomed in, that will result in very jagged looking geometry.
Since each pixel is being treated as a square edged part of the geometry.

Couldn't you get your hands on the original vector (bezier curve) geometry for each glyph you are drawing?

Transforming that into triangle strips and fans would look smoother.